# javax JavaCompiler classpath issues

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to compile some code using the Javax.tools.javacompiler, however each time the compiler does not think that the interfaces the class uses are not part of the classpath.

The interfaces are part of the application that is calling the compiler, and I tried adding the .jar file to the classpath for the javacompiler as so:

```
optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";" + f.getAbsolutePath());

JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, optionList, null,
                compilationUnits);
```

The errors I'm getting are as so:

```
plugins\Ping.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
public class Ping extends BaseRoute {
                          ^
```

And a bunch more stuff caused by it not finding the superclass.

I've made sure to check that the file 'f' is properly defined in debug mode so that isn't the issue. I have also tried adding it to the classpath via `io.asecta.restdb.*` (my package) but that also didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Define "tried adding it to the classpath via `io.asecta.restdb.*` (my package) ".

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling from your own jar file, the java.class.path should already contain your jar file, so no need to add it again via f.getAbsolutePath(), it doesn't hurt but isn't necessary. The code looks absolutely fine to me. Are you sure that in the code you're compiling that you imported this "BaseRoute" class?